# django - subidas multiples para multiples post

Tags: django

soy nuevo en django y estoy haciendo un proyecto de música.

quiero seleccionar **múltiples mp3** y subirlo, que luego me aparezca el formulario para editar los parámetros para cada mp3 por separado (ejemplo, artista, titulo, imagen, etc).
subir múltiples archivos en un input, para editar luego por entradas separadas en la misma pagina
aqui el contenido del models

```
class Contenido(models.Model):
  
# artistas = models.ForeignKey(Artista, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
artistas = models.ManyToManyField(Artista)
titulo = models.CharField('Titulo', max_length=100, blank=True, help_text="Titulo del Contenido")
# album = models.CharField('Albumes', max_length=200)
mp3_cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/mp3_cover', blank=True, null=True, help_text="Cover del MP3")
mp3_upload = models.FileField(upload_to='media/mp3_files', blank=True, null=True, help_text="Archivo MP3")
# colaboraciones = models.ForeignKey(Artista, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
lirica_url_txt = models.URLField('Lirica Texto', blank=True, help_text="Enlace de la Lirica")
lirica_url_video = models.URLField('Lirica Video', blank=True, help_text="Video de la Lirica")
mp3_url_video = models.URLField('Video Youtube', blank=True, help_text="Video Oficial del Contenido")
decada = models.CharField('Decada', max_length=5, choices=DECADA_CHOICES, blank=True, help_text="Selecciona la decada de Creacion")
cont_tipo = models.ForeignKey(ContenidoTipo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Tipo de Contenido", blank=True, null=True, help_text="Tipo de Contenido")
genero = models.ForeignKey(Genero, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Genero", blank=True, null=True, help_text="Selecciona el Genero Musical")
visitas = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
slug = models.SlugField(editable=False, max_length=300, blank=True)
```

aqui el contenido en el views que estado probando pero no logro hacer nada

```
def uploadFile(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    # Fetching the form data
    fileTitle = request.POST["fileTitle"]
    uploadedFile = request.FILES["uploadedFile"]        

    # Saving the information in the database
    document = models.Contenido(
        titulo = fileTitle,
        mp3_upload = uploadedFile
    )
    document.save()

documents = models.Contenido.objects.all()

return render(request, "upload.html", context = {
    "files": documents
})
```

el codigo html que e estado buscando por google

```
<form action="{% url 'contenido_app:uploadFile' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="fileTitle" placeholder="Enter a title">
    <input type="file" name="uploadedFile" multiple>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>            
        <th>File Path</th>
        {% comment %} <th>Upload Date & Time</th> {% endcomment %}
    </tr>
    {% for file in files %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ file.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ file.titulo }}</td>                
            <td>{{ file.mp3_upload.url }}</td>
            {% comment %} <td>{{ file.dateTimeOfUpload }}</td> {% endcomment %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

gracias

Answer (score 0):

Mira por la parte del backend puedo ayudarte a guardar multiples archivos desde un input, lo que tienes que hacer es tener tu función definida, obteniendo los archivos y después haciendo un listado de cada archivo y trabajarlo uno por uno de la siguiente forma (nota: cambiare uploadedFile  por uploadedFiles en plural) :

```
data = request.FILES
uploadedFiles = data.getlist('uploadedFiles')
for single_file in uploadedFiles :
    document = models.Document(
        title = fileTitle,
        uploadedFile = single_file.temporary_file_path()#Ruta directa del archivo
    )
    document.save()
```

Ya apartir de aquí tendrás tus archivos guardados, pero le veo la contra de que todas las canciones tendrán el mismo nombre ya que solo tienes un input para toda una sección de canciones, pudieras obtener el nombre del archivo en cuestion y ponerselo de nombre usando `pathlib` tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera e ignorando el input "**fileTitle**":

```
from pathlib import Path
    data = request.FILES
    uploadedFiles = data.getlist('uploadedFiles')
    for single_file in uploadedFiles :
    path = single_file.temporary_file_path()
        document = models.Document(
            title = Path(path).stem,#nombre del archivo obtenido de la ruta
            uploadedFile = path#Ruta directa del archivo
        )
        document.save()
```

Lo que hace `Path(path).stem` es obtener el nombre del archivo eliminando la ruta en donde se encuentra y la extensión del archivo mismo.
Si quieres comprender más sobre nombres de rutas y archivos en python entra a [Aquí](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

Comment: muchisimas lo probare, si estaria interesante poder sacarle el nombre completo a cada archivo y ponerselo como tititulo, no se si tambien se podria sacara los artistas y ponerselo a su campo y en el front que cada uno tenga su pk

muchas gracias nuevamente